# Rest Assured Exception - invalid JSON Schema, cannot continue

Tags: jsonschema, rest-assured, hamcrest

I am using TestNG along with Rest Assured.
We have json schema file. Inside the Json schema it refers to other schema using $ref attribute.

When I use matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath for Hamcrest assertion it is failing with an validation error.
The error is basically the Validator is unable to read the nested JSON schema.
Can someone help me to resolve the issue.

Error and the Json schemas are attached.

**Error:**

```
com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.exceptions.InvalidSchemaException: 
fatal: invalid JSON Schema, cannot continue
Syntax errors:
[ {
  "level" : "warning",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "file:/C:/GitWorkspace/OM/service_OM/functionalTest/target/test-classes/specs/specification/v1/schema/response/response.json#",
    "pointer" : ""
  },
  "domain" : "syntax",
  "message" : "the following keywords are unknown and will be ignored: [javaType, name]",
  "ignored" : [ "javaType", "name" ]
}, {
  "level" : "error",
  "message" : "value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])",
  "domain" : "syntax",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "file:/C:/GitWorkspace/OM/service_OM/functionalTest/target/test-classes/specs/specification/v1/schema/response/service_header.json#",
    "pointer" : ""
  },
  "keyword" : "required",
  "found" : "boolean",
  "expected" : [ "array" ]
}, {
  "level" : "error",
  "message" : "URI \"./service_header.json\" is not normalized",
  "domain" : "syntax",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "file:/C:/GitWorkspace/OM/service_OM/functionalTest/target/test-classes/specs/specification/v1/schema/response/service_header.json#",
    "pointer" : "/properties/service_header"
  },
  "keyword" : "$ref",
  "value" : "./service_header.json"
}, {
  "level" : "error",
  "message" : "value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])",
  "domain" : "syntax",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "file:/C:/GitWorkspace/OM/service_OM/functionalTest/target/test-classes/specs/specification/v1/schema/response/service_header.json#",
    "pointer" : "/properties/service_header"
  },
  "keyword" : "required",
  "found" : "boolean",
  "expected" : [ "array" ]
}, {
  "level" : "error",
  "message" : "value has incorrect type (found boolean, expected one of [array])",
  "domain" : "syntax",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "file:/C:/GitWorkspace/OM/service_OM/functionalTest/target/test-classes/specs/specification/v1/schema/response/service_item.json#",
    "pointer" : "/properties/items"
  },
  "keyword" : "required",
  "found" : "boolean",
  "expected" : [ "array" ]
}, {
  "level" : "error",
  "message" : "URI \"./setvice_item.json\" is not normalized",
  "domain" : "syntax",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "file:/C:/GitWorkspace/OM/service_OM/functionalTest/target/test-classes/specs/specification/v1/schema/response/service_item.json#",
    "pointer" : "/properties/items/items"
  },
  "keyword" : "$ref",
  "value" : "./service_item.json"
} ]
level: "fatal"
```

JSON Schema:

**main.json**

```
{ 
   "type":"object",
   "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/hyper-schema",
   "name": "Response",
   "title": "Response",
   "javaType": "com.ruthresh.Response",
   "description": "Enables you to make a POST response.",
   "required":true,
   "properties":{
       "service_header":{
           "type":"object",
           "description": "The service header for a response.",
           "required":true,
           "$ref":"./service_header.json"
       },
       "items":{
           "type":"array",
           "description": "An array of individual items.",
           "required":true,
           "maxLength":5000,
           "minLength":1,
           "items":{
                "$ref":"./service_item.json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**service_header.json**

```
{
    "type":"object",
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/hyper-schema",
    "name":"service_header",
    "title":"Service response Header",
    "description":"The service header for a response.",
    "id":"service_header:v1",
    "javaType": "com.ruthresh.Header",
    "required":true,
    "properties":{
        "email_subject":{
            "type":"string",
            "description":"Email subject.",
            "maxLength":255
        },
        "email_message":{
            "type":"string",
            "description":"Email Message.",
            "maxLength":4000
        }
    }
}
```

**serivice_item.json**

```
{
    "type":"object",
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/hyper-schema",
    "name":"serivice_item",
    "title":"Service response Header",
    "description":"The service header for a response.",
    "id":"serivice_item:v1",
    "javaType": "com.ruthresh.Item",
    "required":true,
    "properties":{
        "item_subject":{
            "type":"string",
            "description":"Item subject.",
            "maxLength":255
        },
        "item_message":{
            "type":"string",
            "description":"Item Message.",
            "maxLength":4000
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, "required" should be an array of required properties and not boolean.